# How to split row from table if column exceeds the page capacity in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Below I have a script that contains a 5th text column that had so much written it exceeded the size of the page. Though I added `longtable = T` and `latex_options= "repeat_header"` it only continues the table through multiple pages but if the row exceeds the page it gets cut off. How can I keep the table moving along while not losing text.

```
df %>%
kableExtra::kbl(.,booktabs = T,longtable = T)%>%    
row_spec(0,background = "#F6F6F6",color="black")%>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", font_size = 9,latex_options = 
c("hold_position","repeat_header"),position = "left") %>%
column_spec(1,width = "2.0cm") %>%
column_spec(2,width = "2.5cm") %>%
column_spec(3,width = "2.5cm") %>%
column_spec(4,width = "4.5cm")%>%
column_spec(5,width="10.0cm")
```

Comment: Have you tried rotating the table to landscape?

Comment: its rotated in landscape. `classoption: landscape `

Comment: Is the problem that text is not wrapping? Assuming you are using A4 paper at landscape the width of the page (297mm - margins) seems to be adequate for your table which seems to be 165mm wide. Could you post an image of the problem?

Comment: the text is wrapping, but when it exceeds the page capacity the rest of the text gets lost and the remaining words get cut off at the bottom.

Comment: So are you saying you have one cell in column 5 which contains more text than can be fitted in a complete page?

Comment: Exactly this is the problem. I shift the column length but i can foresee in the future though a text input that is very long and i would not want it to get lost.

Comment: Ok that's helpful to have worked out the nature of the problem. I suspect the answer to this is to be found by modifying your text or data rather than tinkering with kableExtra, or there may be a latex option. See this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24374/big-table-with-cells-spanning-more-than-one-page. It seems to be a Latex issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround by splitting the cell with long text. It works by splitting the text into two chunks based on word count so could easily be adjusted by trial and error.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(kableExtra)
library(wakefield) # for generating long text
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

```
````

````
```{r df, include=FALSE}

set.seed(123)

#sample dataset

df <- data.frame(a = 1:6,
                 b = month.name[1:6],
                 c = names(mtcars)[1:6],
                 d = names(islands)[1:6],
                 e = c(paragraph(2), paste(paragraph(6), collapse = "; "), paragraph(3)))

#create new data frame, cells with long text split into to
df_new <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(f = ifelse(str_length(e)>2000, word(e, 301, -1), NA_character_),
         e = ifelse(str_length(e)>2000, word(e, 1, 300), e)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(f, e), values_to = "e") %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  arrange(a, name) %>% 
  select(-name)

```
````

````
```{r long-table, results='asis'}

df_new %>%
kbl(booktabs = TRUE, 
    longtable = TRUE) %>%
  row_spec(0, background = "#F6F6F6", color = "black") %>%
  landscape() %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped",
              font_size = 9,
              latex_options = c("hold_position","repeat_header"),position = "left") %>%
  column_spec(1, width = "2.0cm") %>%
  column_spec(2, width = "2.5cm") %>%
  column_spec(3, width = "2.5cm") %>%
  column_spec(4, width = "4.5cm") %>%
  column_spec(5, width = "10.0cm")

```
````

Comment: Also the page can fit in more. It seems to get cut off at half the page.